# After taking picture from camera image is not fitting to full screen in android

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera

Below is my code, if a picture is taken from camera after that when setting to subsampling imageview it is setting the image size to small, not to full screen.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Bitmap thumbnail;
private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;
private Button btnSelect;
private String userChoosenTask;
ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri;
SubsamplingScaleImageView ivImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
    ivImage = (SubsamplingScaleImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

    btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });

    mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
  
}

private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo",
            "Cancel"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    cameraIntent();

            }else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

private void cameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
         if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    mArrayUri.add(getImageUri(MainActivity.this, thumbnail));
    ivImage.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(thumbnail).dimensions(4128, 3096));
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
  }
}
```

Xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSelectPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Photo" />
</LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Gradle add these line

```
 compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.5.0'
```

[image: This is the output after taking picture from camera]

Can anyone help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {

       //mArrayUri.add(getImageUri(MainActivity.this, thumbnail));
        String ImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(context, data.getData());
        ivImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImagePath));
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: wait i will try

Comment: we cannot set like this it is  SubsamplingScaleImageView ivImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImagePath));

Answer (score 1):

Basically `thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` will return only thumb size image, which is useful to set in small thumb size image only. If you try to set thumb size image in full screen it can be distorted. So I would suggest change your code for the full-size image. 
To get the full-size image here is the link for camera intent demo application provided by google. 
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Answer (score 0):

After you are setting the image, call `ivImage.setMinimumScaleType(SubsamplingScaleImageView.SCALE_TYPE_CENTER_CROP)`, you can change your code like below:

```
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    mArrayUri.add(getImageUri(MainActivity.this, thumbnail));
    ivImage.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(thumbnail).dimensions(4128, 3096));
    ivImage.setMinimumScaleType(SubsamplingScaleImageView.SCALE_TYPE_CENTER_CROP);
}
```

Got this from the [configuration doc](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view/wiki/07.-Configuration#setminimumscaletypeint) of this `imageView` library.

Comment: you can refer and try other configuration settings provided in docs then.